# Distributed Cache Service in SharePoint - what SharePoint features/roles are dependent on it?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Can somebody explain me if Distributed Cache Service in SharePoint Server 2013 are required part of SharePoint deployments from Microsoft point of view? Any other features or SharePoint deployment scenarios which make this service required? What other components of SharePoint Server have dependency (preferable documented one) from this service to work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is must have component of the SharePoint 2013.

The Newsfeed and the Distributed Cache service support this microblog functionality in SharePoint Server 2013. The Distributed Cache service provides in-memory caching services and does not have a dependency on databases for several features in SharePoint Server 2013. Some of the features that use the Distributed Cache service include:

- Newsfeeds
- Authentication
- OneNote client access
- Security Trimming
- Page load performance

When the service is enabled, these features use the Distributed Cache for quick data retrieval. Blob Cache and Output Cache do not use a distributed caching service since these types of cache exist on each Web Front End server in the farm.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d2ee01/distributed-cache-service-in-sharepoint-2013/

The microblog features and feeds rely on the Distributed Cache to store data for very fast retrieval across all entities.Following activities depend upon on news feed.

- **Microblog activities**   This includes posts, replies, likes, mentions, or tagging an item.
- **Following activities**   This includes when a user follows people, documents, sites, or tags.
- **User profile activities**   This includes birthday, job title change, anniversary, updates made to Ask Me About, creating a new blog post, or posting on a Community Site.
- **Document activities**   This includes when a document is edited or a document is shared.

From the below technet, read this table: [Different caches that depend on the Distributed Cache service](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/jj219700.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I saw similar information before, but "must have" and "features which use it" wording sounds like we talk about enhancements. My question was when and for what it is ABSOLYTELY REQUIRED (preferably backed with references to Microsoft documentation). Also I guess being misconfigured in distributed SharePoint environments this service can cause problems, so I want to now when this service is absolutely necessary. What parts of SP will not work without it at all?

Comment: check my updated answer with technet article.

Comment: Thanks for this. Also put extra thank you on my blog, hope you don't mind :) http://mikerodionov.com/2014/12/15/k2-for-sharepoint-and-sharepoint-2013-distributed-cache-service/